# ccs c inc compiler, result after preprocessing step

Tags: microcontroller, pic, preprocessor

With the gcc compiler if we put

```
gcc -E
```

We get the c code after the preprocessing step.
By curiosity, I was wondering if one could do the same thing with the [CCS C Inc](http://www.ccsinfo.com/compdemo.php) compiler. I tried to look a bit in the [manual](http://www.ccsinfo.com/downloads/ccs_c_manual.pdf) in particular in the **file format** section and in the **invoking the command line compiler** section but I didn't found anything, also I didn't understand so well so maybe I missed something.
Does someone know how to do this (getting the C file just after the preprocessing step, i.e. the same we would get with gcc -E with gcc compiler?)

Comment: Not all C compilers will give the output of the preprocessing.  Do you need to use it for something?  Have you tried the +Z option - is the preprocessed output in one of the scratch files?

Comment: It seems there is no output of preprocessing. The compiler directly converts to binary.

Comment: What do you do with the preprocessed output?  Do you need a macro generator?